# Term for a humorously hypocritical last sentence at the end of a lecture

Tags: single-word-requests

At the end of a [long lecture on proper behaviour](https://twitter.com/differentoceans/status/756394514940518401) by Pokémon Go players, there's a request to let the Shrine Priest know about any rare Pokémon, indicating that they're playing the game as well. Is there a term for such a sentence? I want to use it as follows:

> At the end of a long lecture about proper Pokémon Go behaviour, there was a ____.

Comment: **Plot twist!**

Comment: He closed his a lecture with a humorous *quip*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider ***[punch line](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/punch-line?q=punchline)*** or ***[punchline](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/punch-line?q=punchline)***, defined as:

> The final phrase or sentence of a joke or story, providing the humor or some other crucial element.

This definition explicitly allows that a punchline may appear at the end of something other than a joke, for example, a story.

A punchline might also appear at the end of a humorous notice warning Pokémon Go players about disrespectful behavior. The presence of a punchline does not necessarily mean the notice was written completely in jest.

The final sentence of the notice you link to certainly has the feel of a classic punchline. It's unexpected and humorous. Everything else in the passage misdirects readers from thinking the priest also plays the game. This material is called the ***set-up***.

*Punchline* works well in your example:

> At the end of a long notice about proper Pokémon Go behaviour, there was an unexpected punchline.

---

You might also say that there was a ***humorous twist***, where ***[twist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twist)*** means:

> an unexpected development of events.

In your sentence:

> At the end of a long notice about proper Pokémon Go behaviour, there was a humorous twist.

Comment: I like "humorous twist" better than "punchline".

Answer (score 5):

The "Kicker"

Something that provides a big kick or thrill.

The point of a joke; the fallacy  in an argument; an item in a group that invalidates, negates, or makes worthless all the others.

"The kicker to this one is simple, but the background is…involved.…", *NYTimes Magazine*, Gilbert Milstein April 8, 1951 17/2

Answer (score 3):

possibly **tag line** (or tagline)

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tag-line)

> 1. the last line of a play, story, speech, etc., used to clarify or dramatize a point.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tagline)

> 1 :  a final line (as in a play or joke); especially :  one that serves to clarify a point or create a dramatic effect

[American Heritage dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tag%20line)

> 2. An ending line, as in a play or joke, that makes a point.

Answer (score 1):

I might use "zinger." As far as I know, it's another perhaps more colloquial form of "kicker," but I will edit this post shortly with some more info. I'm on my phone at the moment.